# CakePHP error message position

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

**EDITED**

**CakePHP Version: 2.2.4**

When an input validation falis the error message that CakePHP generates is positioned after my input element

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Name <span class="required-field">*</span></label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input name="data[User][name]" class="input-xlarge form-error" type="text" value="">
            <div class="error-message">This field cannot be left blank.</div>
            <input type="hidden" name="data[User][public_name]" id="UserPublicName_" value="0">
           <input type="checkbox" name="data[User][public_name]" class="span1" value="1">
        </div>
 </div>
```

But I want to place it after my checkbox, like this:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Name <span class="required-field">*</span></label>
        <div class="controls">
           <input name="data[User][name]" class="input-xlarge form-error" type="text" value="">
           <input type="hidden" name="data[User][public_name]" id="UserPublicName_" value="0">
           <input type="checkbox" name="data[User][public_name]" class="span1" value="1">
           <div class="error-message">This field cannot be left blank.</div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

I've read [FormHelper::input()](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/form-helper#method-FormHelperinput) but I can't figure how I can do it. I would like to use `inputDefaults`.

**EDITED**

My .ctp

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Nanme <span class="required-field">*</span></label>
        <div class="controls">
            <?php
               echo $this->Form->input('name', array(
                   'type' => 'text', 'class' => 'input-xlarge'));
               echo $this->Form->checkbox('public_name', array('class' => 'span1'));
            ?>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you post your ctp? I guess you have 2 input "name" and "public_name".

Comment: As a general hint: In asking for CakePHP question you have to identify the version of CakePHP that you use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually I've resolved it. I've add `'error' => false` and positioned the error message where I wanted with `$this->Form->error()`

My .ctp

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Nanme <span class="required-field">*</span></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <?php
           echo $this->Form->input('name', array(
               'type' => 'text', 'class' => 'input-xlarge', 'error' => false));
           echo $this->Form->checkbox('public_name', array('class' => 'span1'));
           echo $this->Form->error('User.name', null, array('class' => 'error-message'));
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The 'checkbox' input type should already be putting the error after the input.

But to specify the exact order, use the `format` key in input's `$options` array:

```
$this->Form->input('fieldname', 
    array('type'=>'checkbox',
          'format'=>array('before', 'input', 'between', 'label', 'after', 'error')
));
```

Just change the order of those array elements to match what you need.

Comment: Thanks, but what I don't know is how to order the array elements. Additionally I would like to use 'inputDefaults' so all my checkboxes appear correctly.

Comment: 'inputDefaults' would apply to all `input()` calls, not just the checkboxes.  I don't understand your issue with ordering the elements? You can do some testing by setting values for `'before' => '--before--', 'after' => '--after--',` etc, so you can see where each appears in the output.

Answer (score 0):

1. in your controller use below syntex

   ```
    if($this->{$this->pageModel}->validates())
    {
       // your code....
    }
    else{
          // your errors 
       $errors = $this->{$this->pageModel}->validationErrors;
       $this->set('errors',$errors);
    }
   ```
2. in your ctp file put below code where you want to show your error message

   ```
   if(isset($errors) && !empty($errors['fieldname']))
   { 
       echo $errors['fieldname'][0];
   }
   ```